# Laptop display drivers not working with Bootable USB

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, drivers

MSI GS66 with i7-10750H and rtx2060

If I try to reinstall Windows using a USB drive, or boot from Hiram's Boot CD PEx64 (burnt onto a USB), the laptop display does not work (the screen is completely black, but I *believe* everything else is working, since with Hiram's Boot USB, I actually hear the log in sound and I can Alt+F4->Enter to turn the computer off while the screen is black. also, if I connect an HDMI display, I hear the device connected sound but still no image). This leads me to believe that everything apart from the display drivers is working.

It is possible that the hardware is too new for the Windows iso and Hiram's Boot CD, but due to some other reasons I wish to boot using an older version of Windows. Any idea how I might be able to get the display to work when booting from a USB under these circumstances?

Alternatively, is it possible to reinstall windows without seeing anything? Can I run blind? Is there a keyboard shortcut that would enable visually impaired screen reading assist etc?

Comment: You say you can reach the login screen.  Try that, click on Power icon on lower right corner, then hold down the SHIFT key and then select Restart.  Press F8 repeatedly and see if you can get into Safe Mode. This may not work if the screen is always black.

Comment: @John I am trying to install windows using an older .iso. At this point windows is not installed.

Comment: Can you download a newer ISO? Graphics systems have a "basic" mode that handles output when there are no drivers though. I'd be willing to guess this is not a driver issue.